# Passing a pointer to objects method safely to google.maps.event.addListener

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, maps

When passing a method pointer to `google.maps.event.addListener`, google maps seems to overwrite it's `this` reference with an instance of `google.maps.Map`, therefore it renders it useless if the methods references any of its prototype memebers internally.

The long story short, if I pass `myObj.MyMethod` as an event callback, at the time of its execution `MyMethod.this` reference will be an instance of `google.maps.Map` rather then `myObj`.

Is there any way to safely pass a method pointer to addListener and maintain all of its references intact ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you passed the method with `addListener()`, The passed object of method would be lost at event occurred, so as a result method is not defined, you should call the method something like

```
google.maps.event.addListener('someEvent', function (){
     myObj.MyMethod.call(myObj); //invoked MyMethod with reference myObj

    //myObj.MyMethod.apply(myObj); <= you can use apply method also
})
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for, works flawlessly, many thanks !