# Google Maps : google.maps.event.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drawing

i have shapes and i draw it in maps :

```
    shapes; //array of shapes, i draw it from string that i take from db

    for (var i = shapes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(shapes[i], 'click', function() {
            myFunc(shapes[i]); //function to edit shapes[i]
        });
    };
```

when i do this :
1. e.g i have shapes length = 5;
2. i click in 1 of the shape but myFunc always called with i=5 so myFunc always call shapes[5]

i already try : [Passing a pointer to objects method safely to google.maps.event.addListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436596/passing-a-pointer-to-objects-method-safely-to-google-maps-event-addlistener)

but still fail, can someone give me advice?

Answer (score 0):

shapes; //array of shapes, i draw it from string that i take from db

```
for (var i = shapes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 (function (i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(shapes[i], 'click', function() {
        myFunc(shapes[i]); //function to edit shapes[i]
    });
 })(i);
};
```